# How to do copy activity sequentially in adf?

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory

I need to copy the files from blob to sFTP. In ADLS gen2 blob storage, there are different File category folder(Ex GST_CASE1,GST_CASE2,GST_CASE3).

Each category folder, there are set of csv files and corresponding ctl(control) files.

On copying, need to copy this .csv and .ctl files(of each category ->GST_CASE1,GST_CASE2) to sFTP location. After copied to sFTP,
these files need to move to achieve folder in blob storage folder.

```
xxx/yyy/GST_CASE1
        gst_case1_20210323113000.csv
        gst_case1_20210323113000.ctl

        gst_case1_20210323114500.csv
        gst_case1_20210323114500.ctl

xxx/yyy/GST_CASE1/archive
        gst_case1_20210323113000.csv  
        gst_case1_20210323113000.ctl


xxx/yyy/GST_CASE2

        gst_case1_20210323113000.csv  
        gst_case1_20210323113000.ctl

        gst_case1_20210323114500.csv
        gst_case1_20210323114500.ctl

xxx/yyy/GST_CASE2/achieve
        gst_case1_20210323113000.csv  
        gst_case1_20210323113000.ctl
```

In this, for each category file, below activities need to perform

```
.csv file to copy to SFTP
.ctl file to copy to SFTP
```

finally move these files to archive folder

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I could have used the foreach activity and inside the FE activity i could have two copy activity one for copying the file to SFTP and to the archive folder. You will also need a lookup activity to feed into the FE activity .

In the  FE activity you will have to mark as sequentials shown below  .

HTH .
[image]